# What techniques do you use to "stack" multiple symbols around a point?

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

I'm working on a map for a trail system. There is a "Camp Store" right next to a "Parking Lot" and I want to show symbols for both without them overlapping each other.

One idea is to have a callout point a location and a row of symbols showing there are multiple facilities at that location. But it could also be without a callout.

Any suggestions for "pleasantly" displaying multiple symbols at a single location/point?

In this instance I'm using QGIS.

Comment: Take a look at Point Displacement renderer

Comment: This : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393863/labelling-features-by-multiple-attributes-in-qgis

Comment: The question got closed and pointed to another one, but I think the Point Displacement Renderer is a better solution.

Comment: @BrianKelly the point displacement renderer will work if you have several point at the same location (ie. a point per symbol), if you have a single point and want to show several symbol depending on attribute the displacement renderer won't work and you will need to use one of the solution in the linked answer. in the end the best answer depend on how your data is organised...