# QGIS gap-free symbology for pipe-separated values of one single column

Tags: qgis, symbology

In QGIS, I have a point-layer with a column named `type`, which contains around 10 different pipe-seperated possible values (for example `A|B|D|E`, `A|B`, `B|C|E`or `B|C` and so on, like in the example-image) (the values represent different tracks and signs of mammal-species).

For each different value I want a defined symbol to be shown, but without any gaps between.

I have managed to build a symbology with seperate symbol-levels with different fixed offsets for each value, wich sizes are set feature-driven with expressions like

```
CASE
WHEN regexp_matches ("type", 'A')
THEN 5
ELSE 0
END
```

This gives me desired symbols, but with a fixed offset for each symbol, which leads to gaps between them whenever a value is missing (for example if the `type` column says `A|C`, there is a gap between the symbols `A` and `C`, because the value `B` is not present).

[image]

Despite being quite complicated, this approach doesn't give me the wanted gap-free symbology...
I have looked up the thread [Labelling features by multiple attributes in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393863/labelling-features-by-multiple-attributes-in-qgis), but this approach needs a separate column for each possible value, which in my case would need a bit of pre-formatting.

Comment: Using the answer that you have linked, you can compute the offset by counting the number of `|` before the icon/class being rendered

Comment: ok, that sounds like a good approach... How exactly would the syntax look like?